# in OnTriggerEnter2D collision.getComponents() throws exception, unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

it is so weird I can't find anyone encounter with this situation.

There are two box collier 2d and one of it was set isTrigger to true.
when Box A collide with Box B, OnTriggerEnter2D fired. I can event get the tag of the collider. But when I call getComponents or getComponent<>, VS2018 said "Exception was thrown by invocation: One or more errors occurred."

What would I miss?

[image: N|Solid]

Comment: There should be an `InnerException` on that exception - what error(s) does that yield?

Comment: @UnholySheep don't know where to find the error messages

Comment: Put a try catch around where you error is happening. And the print the error and also `error.InnerException` and `error.InnerException.Message`

Comment: Apparently, it's a Unity3d limitation that you can't use `GetComponent<>` in Watch window of Visual Studio.

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi that is not true. I have try tutorial project and get what I expect in watch window.

Answer (score 0):

Just from screen i would say you are trying to use Collider2D as gameObject.
Do get component on

```c#
collision.gameObject.GetComponent<...>()
```

to get components and

```c#
collision.gameObject.tag
```

for tag and

```c#
collision.transform
```

if you want to access the other gameObject's transform.

Also I would suggest you to not use name `collision` since the parameter is a `Collider` (which is an object) not a `Collision` (which is an action).

See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html for more

Comment: thanks for your answer. The parameter name is auto-generated, it should be a collier, so I don't need to call getComponent through gameObject